# How to avoid "Received Memory warning" when changing the slider value in order to change the intensity of the image(coreImage)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6

I am trying to implement a method that changes the tone of an image in accordance with the slider value, but when i change the slider value continuously it is showing memory warning and the app crashes.

This is my sample code, I tried using dispatch_async

```
-(void)valueChanged
{
    float slideValue = slider.value;
    NSLog(@"%0.f",slideValue);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0.5), ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [filter setValue:@(slideValue)
                      forKey:@"inputIntensity"];
            CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];


            CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage
                                             fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

            UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
            imageView.image = newImage;


       });

    });

}
```

Comment: Firstly if this your all method you don't need a dispatch. All you do here is calling high priority dispatch queue and in it call main queue

Comment: thank you kuba,but why it is showing memory warning?

Answer (score 7):

You are leaking memory, what means that you are allocating objects that you are not releasing, hence the memory warnings.

Have you tried releasing the images after you have used them?

```
CGImageRelease(cgimg)
```

At the end of the method

Comment: it requires 15 reputation,as i'm new to this site.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001310-BCIFIFEE) for `createCGImage:fromRect:` API, for return value it says,

> You are responsible for releasing the returned image when you no longer need it.

Which means you are leaking memory for `cgimg` instance. As suggested by Antonio MG you should release the reference at the end. The `imageWithCGImage:` will retain it, so no need to worry.

Hope that helps!